# How to use "search_people" function correctly when import linkedin-api in Python?

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'd followed the document [Link](https://linkedin-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#linkedin_api.Linkedin.search_people)
and given the params (keywords and regions),
but the return values were not correct.

For example :

```
from linkedin_api import Linkedin
api = Linkedin( user_account , user_password )
res = api.search_people( 
    keywords = 'elons' ,
    regions = ['105117694']
)
print( len(res) )
>> it only 14 results
```

and I manually performed the same params on website, it got 30 results
[refer pic](https://filedn.com/lITVpx0zTSFLj1XgF9JCPXX/linked.png)

Can somebody help me with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it returns "minimal data only".

Comment: Yeah I know that, I mean the total search result counts 
Why's different between manual operation and script return result

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).